aws ssm agent log files with older timestamps
fairly new AWS (cloudops) user here.
So on 10/28:

I ran some Terraform code which creates EC2 image builder resources (Components, ImageBuilder Pipeline, etc).
then in AWS console I ran that ImageBuilder Pipeline to generate an AMI.

On 11/01:

I ran some Terraform code which creates an EC2 instance (from the above AMI).

Now on initial RDP into the EC2 instance, I'm looking at the various SSM logs:
 Directory of C:\ProgramData\Amazon\SSM\Logs

10/09/2024  02:12 AM    <DIR>          .
10/09/2024  02:12 AM    <DIR>          ..
11/01/2024  05:44 PM            43,858 amazon-ssm-agent.log
10/09/2024  02:12 AM            16,811 AmazonSSMAgent-update.txt
11/01/2024  03:44 PM    <DIR>          audits
11/01/2024  03:53 PM            85,597 errors.log
11/01/2024  05:55 PM           651,241 ssm-agent-worker.log
11/01/2024  04:06 PM           488,006 ssm-document-worker.log

Interestingly, most have entries from 3 different dates:
2024-10-09
2024-10-28
2024-11-01

Obviously 10-28 was AMI creation...and 11-01 was EC2 creation.  But why would there be log entries from the earlier date (10-09)?
The content on 10-09 is similar to the later dates...for example in amazon-ssm-agent.log:
2024-10-09 01:36:55 INFO Starting up windows agent
2024-10-09 01:36:55 INFO Waiting for system state
2024-10-09 01:36:56 INFO System is ready
2024-10-09 01:36:56 INFO Starting up agent subsystem
2024-10-09 01:36:56 INFO Getting IE proxy configuration for current user: The operation completed successfully.
2024-10-09 01:36:56 INFO Getting WinHTTP proxy default configuration: The operation completed successfully.
2024-10-09 01:36:56 INFO Proxy environment variables:
2024-10-09 01:36:56 INFO https_proxy: 
2024-10-09 01:36:56 INFO http_proxy: 
2024-10-09 01:36:56 INFO no_proxy: 
2024-10-09 01:36:56 INFO Checking if agent identity type OnPrem can be assumed
2024-10-09 01:36:56 INFO Checking if agent identity type EC2 can be assumed
2024-10-09 01:36:56 INFO Agent will take identity from EC2
2024-10-09 01:36:56 INFO [amazon-ssm-agent] Not using named pipe on windows

Thanks.

SSM Agent depends on OS for time. I was able to reproduce and from what I've seen the Event Viewer for System Events also logged other events unrelated to SSM Agent from 10/9 on the latest Amazon Windows Server 2019 AMI, this is suggesting that the OS operated from boot at this time until it was able to time sync, and any processes that started earlier would have logged the same start time that is likely defined by AMI.

thx @Rocky Li.  Guess the 10/9 timestamps makes sense as that is 1 day after Microsoft's monthly patch Tuesday (2nd Tues == 10/8)...so likely when AWS re-generated the Win2022 AMI (which I failed to mentioned was the base for my AMI).
